# How to receive an array of 16-bit integer tuples from a socket, in Python?

Tags: python

My Python app needs to receive an array of 16-bit integer tuples from a C++ application.

The data consists of an array of 32-bit unsigned integers, where each integer represents an IQ complex number. I and Q are each signed 16-bit numbers.

The array size is constant (6000).

The apps run on similar architectures so I don’t need to worry about endianness.

Please suggest a Python code snippet to read the data from a socket into a list of IQ tuples.  (I know how to create and connect a socket).

Best regards

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has several options to process binary data; in this case, you start out by reading from a socket, producing an immutable bytes buffer (`bytes` in Python 3, `str` in Python 2). This can be parsed as 16-bit words using either [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) or [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array):

```
tuple_of_ints = struct.unpack('=12000h', data)
array_of_s16s = array.array('h', data)
```

From there, you still have only a one-dimensional structure, where odd and even items are your I and Q values. If using [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/), you could use ndarray.fromstring or ndarray.frombuffer to create a similar array, then reshape it.

We could also convert items individually, which is a bit slower:

```
list_of_complex_numbers = [complex(*struct.unpack('hh',data[i:i+4]))
    for i in range(0,len(data),4)]
```

numpy is also capable of reading from file, so with a file-like socket you might be able to use `numpy.fromfile(socket, numpy.int16, 2*6000)`.

Comment: Thanks very much. That's very helpful.

Comment: Please will you explain the fmt: '=12000h' ?

Comment: If you follow the link to the documentation for `struct`, you'll find that `=` means native byte order, `12000` is the number of items and `h` (mnemonic: half word) is for 16-bit signed integers. `hh` could equally be written `2h`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **struct** library in python is you have incoming data as hexadecimal bytes.

Or if they are simple hexadecimal numbers then conversion is direct.

It would be really helpful if you can tell the data type you receive from C++ and the required format in python.

Comment: The array is a packed array of  pairs of 16-bit two's complement integers.  Each successive pair of 16-bit integers should be assigned to a Python tuple of integers (ideally also 16-bit in case I need to do bit manipulation on them).

Comment: struct has nothing to do with hexadecimal representations; it processes binary data.

Comment: You can use ctypes in python for restrictng the size of integer to 16 bit. The unpacking and conversion of variables is possible by struct library.